# Cannot import JSX/TSX component from another React app to my main React app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, npm-link

I have a fairly complex setup regarding two React apps.

**Context:**
I was tasked to create a design system using ReactJS to be later on used in their main app.
So i did made a design system in 1 week (w/ small knowledge in ReactJS; mainly a Vue dev) made with `NextJS + TailwindCSS 3 + TypeScript` in their latest versions.

Now i got their main React app downloaded locally; not Typescript, and all packages were outdated already using node 6 and react 16.13. So i updated them to node 16 and React 17 along with other packages.

Also main app doesn't use functional components while mine does.

**Problem:**
Now the problem is how do i connect the two apps? The main app (non TS) and my design system (TS with NextJS) so i could use my design system components on their app?

**What i've tried to do so far:**
I used `npm-link` to link my design system npm to the main app. The link was successful however main app cannot find my `tsx` files.

Also tried building my design system app by `next build` .

I tried two things on importing:

**Importing a TSX component**
I tried importing by `import SearchBar from "design-system/components/SearchBar";` and was met with error `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve`.

**Importing a JSX component**
Tried importing a `Test` jsx component from my design system and met with error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:9)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| 
| export default function Test() {
>   return <div>TEST COMPONENT FROM JS</div>;
| }
|
```

**Notes**

- Also take note that design system uses functional components while main app doesn't.
- I was under impression that i could use any framework in design system regardless of what React or does app have TS or not, since it will be a npm package even if it's not published yet, and thought can import it and use it anywhere as long as it is React.
- main app was created with `react-scripts`; design system was created with `create next-app --typescript`

Here's my `ts.config.json` from the design system app

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "."],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "moduleResolution": ["node_modules", ".next", "node"]
}
```

**What steps should i make?**

- Should i adjust my design system to use Class-based components and use JSX instead of TS?
- Is there anything i can do on the main app to be able to import JSX or preferably TSX files from another react node app?
- Should i make a new `create-react-app` or just start from scratch without NextJS for design system? NextJS wasn't really needed in my components.

Comment: You can use function components from the design system in your app even if the app only uses class components, as long as you're using React >=16.8. However, you do have to compile your design system components so they're usable by your app. Also, Next.js is most likely not needed to simply build components for a design system - you'd want to use Next.js in the app itself instead.

Comment: @juliomalves thank you. I've actually been learning that

- NextJS is not suitable for building react "libraries".
- Rollup is more suited for libraries and publishing to NPM.

Since then i was able to create a framework from scratch using React + TypeScript + TailwindCSS + Rollup and able to use it on my main app. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So for several days, i have learned that what i was building were React "library" and React app.

The library part is important since you need to use some specific bundlers such as `Rollup` instead of `Vite`, `Parcel`, etc... and doesn't have to use `create-react-app` since it's a high level abstraction for creating React Apps instead.

If you have the same problem:

- Don't use create-react-app or NextJS
- Use bundlers suited for bundling components such as `Rollup`
- Configure your Rollup to produce both CommonJS and ESModules. There are tons of tutorial for that.
- You may use Barrel exports